How to return null values from quarkus native built application?
I have a PostgreSQL database with columns that can contain null values. If I use quarkus dev mode or jvm, the query returns (correctly) null values. However, if I build with the native profile using GraalVM, it returns 0 for Integer and 0.0 for Float (instead of null).
I am using the quarkus-resteasy-jsonb extension and the following image during my multistage docker build:
FROM quay.io/quarkus/ubi-quarkus-mandrel-builder-image:22.3-java17 AS build
...
What has already been tested:

Annotate my entities with @RegisterForReflection (but as the already have @Entity as annotation, they should not be left apart by GraalVM)
Annotate the Integer and Float fields with @JsonBNillable (I use the quarkus-resteasy-jsonb extenstion)
Went down the GraalVM way and created a META-INF/native-image/reflect-config.json like explained by quarkus docs here: https://quarkus.io/guides/writing-native-applications-tips#using-a-configuration-file-2
Added a custom JsonbConfigCustomizer like described by Guillaume Smet in the post here: How to return fields with null values in QUARKUS Resteasy JSONB and override sorted keys? (Narayanan's answer from 8th October 2020)
Unfortunately none of them worked so far.

Could be related to this: Quarkus numeric type (Integer, Float) return 0 instead of null
Here is the beginning of my entity class:
@Entity
@Table(name = DBUtils.MY_TABLE_NAME, schema = DBUtils.SCHEMA_NAME)
@Getter
@Setter
public class MyClass extends PanacheEntityBase {

private static Logger technicalLogger = Logger.getLogger(LoggerNames.TECHNICAL.getName());

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "myclassSequenceGenerator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "myclassSequenceGenerator", sequenceName  = "myclass_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)

@Column(name = "myclass_id", nullable = false)
public int myclassId;

@Column(name = "myclass_name", length = 50)
public String myclassName;

@Column(name = "street_length_m", length = 5)
public Integer lengthInMeters;  // <= gives 0 if null in DB

@Column(name = "street_length_km", length = 5)
public Float lengthInKilometers; // <= gives 0.0 if null in DB 
...

Any help would be highly appreciated. Many thanks in advance!

can you share your @Entity class ? or better a small reproducer ?

Hi @ozkanpakdil, thank you for replying. I added the beginning of my entity class for now

can you try without lombok and one more step can you try with nullable true please.

Yes I tried both, but without success unfortunately. @Column(nullable=true/false) is for adding constraints (or not) to the database during generation process. Any other idea? Thanks a lot in advance!

With the same configuration, Jackson instead of Jsonb, with GraalVM with Java21, this error is not hapenning.
If you are using Active Record strategy, Lombok is not needed.
There are an issue opened
https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/5672
I would try:

promote to the latest version of Quarkus
promote to GraalVM with Java 21
remove Lombok because the properties are public
And if it still fails
I would try changing Jsonb for Jackson.
make sure you have the reactive rest client and reactive rest client serialization libraries (jackson and jsonb)


Thank's a lot Juan for helping me out. I will try your suggestions one after the other. I was using quarkus 3.8.1 by the way, so I upgrade to 3.10.2 today. Can you please explain why I need the reactive versions of these extensions ?

In [https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/wiki/Migration-Guide-2.8](Migration Guide 2.8) explains that RESTEasy Reactive by default.
In [https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/wiki/Migration-Guide-3.9#resteasy-reactive-extensions-renamed-to-quarkus-rest-gear-white_check_mark](Migration Guide 3.9) gives the new names for this dependencies.
Now, 3.10, this libraries are reactive, blocking and non-blocking.
quarkus-rest and quarkus-rest-jackson was called "reactive" in previous versions

Thank you for the information. However, I need @SessionScoped which currently cannot be used with quarkus-rest, so I need to stay with the resteasy "classic". Anyway the problem could be solved thanks to upgrading to java21 and by removing Lombok, thank you very much !
